# trying to load a recource pack when logged into a world

Tags: minecraft

I'm making a Minecraft horror game, and I got stuck on how to automatically load a resource pack when that world is loaded, to make it much easier for people that are gonna play.
Version is `1.19.2.`

I've tried many ways: YouTube, ChatGPT-3, the internet, but only one video on that topic was outdated.
An attempt I tried was to put the `pack.mcmeta` and assets folder into a zip then put it into the world and then rename it into `resources.zip`, and later `resourcepacks.zip`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Default resource packs can be fairly easy to set on a world:

(Abstract from [Minecraft Wiki's article on resource-packs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Default_resource_packs))

> A resource pack can be bundled with a world by saving it as a .zip file under the name `resources.zip` and placing it ***directly in the world's folder***. When playing the world, that resource pack appears as the default right above the default resource pack.

All you  need is to rename a working resourcepack as `resources.zip` and add it to your world folder.

As long as the resource-pack's folder structure is valid, it will be added as `World Specific Resources`. Should the `resources.zip` fail to load, the game will issue a warn message `Server resource pack couldn't be applied`

the folder structure can be found on the aforementioned article.

---

Default Resource-packs work differently on servers:

> A resource pack can be set on a server by adding a link to a .zip file download after the line `resource-pack=` in the `server.properties` file. Users then have an option of whether to download the resource pack or not. Resource packs can also be forced on a server using `resource-pack-required=true` in the `server.properties` file. Rejecting the resource pack disconnects the player from the server.